# Combine NSMutableArray with [Swift Array]

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsmutablearray

The goal:
I want to have a computed property which returns an array with different type of objects based on `NSMutableArray` and swift array combination.

Two problem here:

1. Computed property contains code with an `NSMutableArray`
2. I don't know how to combine two arrays. `NSMutableArray` + `[AnyObjct]`

I have an Objective-C class `CentralManager` with a method `storedDevices` that returns `NSMutableArray` with some objects. Example:

```
var wifiDevices = [WifiDevice]()

var allDevices: NSMutableArray {
  get {
    let blueToothDevices = CentralManager.shared().storedDevices
    let devices = blueToothDevices + wifiDevices // it does not work as we can't combine NSMutableArray and swift array.

    return devices
  }
}
```

Also as I use swift not sure that my computed property should return `NSMutableArray`, maybe it's better to return `[AnyObject]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `addObjectsFromArray` method of `NSMutableArray` for that

```
var allDevices: NSMutableArray {
   get {
       var blueToothDevices = CentralManager.shared().storedDevices
       let devices = blueToothDevices.addObjectsFromArray(wifiDevices) 
       return devices
   }
}
```

**Edit:** If you want `allDevices` to be of swift array and your `blueToothDevices` contains `WifiDevice` type of object you can use `[WifiDevice]` like this way.

```
var blueToothDevices = CentralManager.shared().storedDevices
var devices = blueToothDevices.objectEnumerator().allObjects as! [WifiDevice]
let devices = devices + wifiDevices
```

**For Any Object**

```
var allDevices: [AnyObject] {
    get {
        var blueToothDevices = CentralManager.shared().storedDevices
        var blueTooths = blueToothDevices.objectEnumerator().allObjects
        blueTooths = blueTooths + wifiDevices
        return blueTooths
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer! `let devices = devices + wifiDevices` brings this issue `Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type '[BluetothDevice]' and '[WifiDevice]'

Comment: `blueToothDevices.addObjectsFromArray(wifiDevices)  return devices` throws this complier issue: Cannot convert return expression of type 'Void' (aka '()') to return type 'NSMutableArray'

Comment: I have told you it only works if blueToothDevices contains `WifiDevice` object, for this situation you need to convert both array to `[AnyObject]` and than concatenate them with `+` or either use my first answer.

Comment: thanks for details, so in my question `CentralManager.shared().storedDevices` is an `NSMutableArray` which can contain any object right? In Objective-C that type of array can return to you even `NSNumber`, but let's assume that I expect BluetoothDevice objects which I want to set to `let blueToothDevices` and also I have `wifiDevices` array which contains `[WiFiDivice]` model as in my question, so the question is regarding how can I combine these two arrays. Can you show in your answer how to do it, thanks! appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's See Simple Example :

**NSMutableArray**

Take one `NSMutableArray` with two Object "A" and "B"

```
 let mutableArray = NSMutableArray()
 mutableArray.addObject("A")
 mutableArray.addObject("B")
 print(mutableArray)
```

**Swift Array :**

Take Swift Array with two Object "C" and "D"

```
 var swiftArray = [String]()
 swiftArray = ["C" , "D"]
```

**concat two Array**

```
let mutableSwift = mutableArray.objectEnumerator().allObjects as? [String]
swiftArray = swiftArray + mutableSwift!

print(swiftArray)
```

**Finally You Swift Array**

["C", "D", "A", "B"]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but in your case, you have the same types, in my example `CentralManager.shared().storedDevices` can return what ever NSMutableArray can store, but actually it will be BluetoothDevice model and my other swift array contains WifiDevice model, so I am not sure that I can simpe `+` this arrays.

Comment: You can Keep AnyObject. and when you use then Check object is BluetoothDevice or WifiDevice.